# How to see if a view function exists based on a url

Tags: python, django

I am trying to give django a url and resolve it to a view. For example:

```
>>> reverse('login')
'/login/'
>>> reverse('/login/')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Users/david/Desktop/V/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
>       return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
>     File "/Users/david/Desktop/V/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
>       raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Is there another way to do this? Or a django method that I can pass it a url (these will be 'dirty' urls, such as "https://example.com/login/?next=/myaccount/"), and it will resolve it to the correct view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opposite of `redirect` is [**`resolve`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) in the `django.urls` module:

> The `resolve()` function can be used for resolving URL paths to the
>   corresponding view functions. It has the following signature:
>
> **`resolve(path, urlconf=None)`**
>
> `path` is the URL path you want to resolve. As with `reverse()`, you
>   don't need to worry about the `urlconf` parameter. The function
>   returns a `ResolverMatch` object that allows you to access various
>   metadata about the resolved URL.

For example:

```
>>> from django.urls import resolve
>>> resolve('/admin/')
ResolverMatch(func=django.contrib.admin.sites.index, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=index, app_names=['admin'], namespaces=['admin'])
```

This thus returns a `ResolverMatch` that contains the "view" function that will be called together with positional and named parameters, and information about the namespace, name of the app(s), etc.

For URLs that can not be resolved, it will raise a `django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404` error.

Note that the querystring is not part of the `path`. You can extract the path with:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('/login/?next=a')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='/login/', params='', query='next=a', fragment='')
```

So only the `path='...'` part (can be obtained by fetching the `.path` attribute) will determine the view function, the querystring is passed to the view as a dictionary-like object with `request.GET`.

Comment: thanks for this. It seems this works for 'clean' urls, but not if there's any discrepancy. For example: `>>> resolve('/login/')
ResolverMatch(func=users.views.login, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=login, app_names=[], namespaces=[])
>>> resolve('/login/?next=a')` [error]. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @David542: but the `?next=a` part is not part of the path, this is the *querystring*. You can extract the path with the `urlparse` function from the `urlparse` module.